# Is there any specific requirements for RAM to upgrade laptop?

Tags: memory, lenovo-laptop, dell-vostro, ddr

Currently, I have 4GB DDR4 RAM in my Dell Laptop. Previously I had Lenovo laptop with 4GB DDR4 RAM. Now I want to use that Lenovo's RAM in Dell Laptop. Is there any specific RAM requirements for laptop? Can I use that Lenovo's RAM in my Dell laptop? Will any problem occurs due to differentiation in company?

Comment: Use any RAM checker to see what types can be used by a PC, e.g. Crucial's or Kingston's; http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner or https://www.kingston.com/us/memory/search/options

Comment: What is the model number of the laptop?

Comment: Old: Lenovo Ideapad 310 AMD A10; New: Dell Vostro 3478

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the slot/slots for more ram?
 Some won't work beyond a set amount although my computer is OK at twice of what is supposed to be its Max.  Whatever, just try it out. Manufacturer shouldn't matter.
 If it works, good for you.  If it doesn't work put it back the way it worked.
 Btw I'm assuming you know to turn the computer off and how to access the memory etc.